# Thread 1: signal SIGBRT

Tags: ios, crash, xcode7

This message appears next to the line of code after I run the app in the simulated. The build succeeds and the view loads but when I click a button the app crashes. I have done research and couldn't find anything that worked.

Here is my code in main.m:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegateclass]));
     }
}
```

Comment: There should be a space between `AppDelegate` and `class`. This is probably just a typo though (as the compiler shouldn't let you build that), and the source of your problem isn't in your `main.m`. Xcode jumps to this line when it doesn't know exactly where your app crashed. You'll have go through your code with breakpoints to isolate the exact issue.

Comment: Can you give some more details. What does the console say? What is your selector name and can you include your function name here?

Comment: the console says "Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger." and my function creates a UIAlertController Action with the title "Test Title" and the message "Filler Text" @Varun

Comment: As the console says, there are constraints/autolayout issue. Try to fix that. It might resolve the crash

Comment: that fixed my layout problem but the app still crashes @Varun

Comment: Can you add an exception breakpoint. That'll tell you the exact location of the crash. If it still crashes in main, then check if in thread 0, at 0th location, there is something like objc_exception_throw

Comment: I added the breakpoint. There is nothin in the 0thy thread but the 1st thread ha a lot of tape when I open the accordion but the one that is in bold says "22 main" and highlights the line of code in main.m that declares the main storyboard to be cited from the App Delegate. @Varun

Answer (score 0):

right click on button and see if there are two IBAction Assigned?
If yes then remove the one which is not getting used or delete from .h file

Comment: It is only assigned to one action @Dev_Tanel